# C++ Variable length array (VLA) warnings

Tags: c++, new-operator, gcc-warning, nvcc

I read different answers about VLA on SO but couldn't find the answer. In my case, I have one function that allocates memory:

```
template<typename T>
void allocMemory(T *&data, const size_t numElems)
{
   #ifdef PINNED_MEMORY
      // allocate pinned memory
   #else
      data = new T[numElems];
   #endif   
}
```

Now, I have a vector class where I use this method:

```
template<typename T>
class MyVec
{
 T *data;
 size_t size;
public:
 MyVec(size_t _size): size(_size)
 { allocMemory<T>(data, size); } // gives VLA warning
};
```

It happens when I compile it using nvcc (V0.2.1221) compiler which I guess uses gcc compiler  underneath (?) The actual warning is:

myvec.h:16:6: warning: ISO C++ does not support variable-length array types [-Wvla]
           data = new T[numElems];

Comment: have you tried `allocMemory<T>(data, size)` ?

Comment: What's the actual error message you get?

Comment: @Marius oops. yes it is allocMemory<T>(data, size) in the source code.

Comment: a `new T[num]` is not a variable length array at all. If you have `int i; int j[i];` you call it VLA.

Comment: If this gets compiled with NVCC, make sure the error isn't somewhere else or that you have a __CUDACC__ macro somewhere so that you're really compiling some other part of the coe

Comment: No warning [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c542cc15ca654a87)... can you give an example that actually cause the warning? Which compiler are you using? Which version? Which platform?

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't compile your project the right way.

Try to using the flowing make file.

> CUDA_INSTALL_PATH := /usr/local/cuda

```
CXX := g++
CC := gcc
LINK := g++ -fPIC
NVCC  := nvcc

 #Includes

INCLUDES = -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include

 #Common flags

COMMONFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
NVCCFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)

LIB_CUDA := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -lcudart

#OBJS = GpuSolver.cu.o main.cpp.o

OBJS = main.cu.o a.cpp.o # your files

TARGET = a.out

LINKLINE = $(LINK) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIB_CUDA)

.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .cu .o

%.c.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.cu.o: %.cu
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) "makefile" #your makefile file name
    $(LINKLINE)
```

Comment: CUDA_INSTALL_PATH?